# Xcode| SDK 6 iOS 4.3+

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

I have a `problem` to run `application` in my `iPad(5.1.1)`. I work with the new `Xcode` and `sdk6`.

i get this `error` in the debugger:

```
 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x355df88f 0x33203259 0x355df789 0x355df7ab 0x32fc654d 0x32fc66bb 0x32fc6423 0x32f57001 0x32ec53c7 0x32da2c59 0x32d18c17 0x32d17461 0x32d09e87 0x32d7a7d5 0xd2701 0x32d17cab 0x32d117dd 0x32cdfac3 0x32cdf567 0x32cdef3b 0x332d122b 0x355b3523 0x355b34c5 0x355b2313 0x355354a5 0x3553536d 0x32d1086b 0x32d0dcd5 0xd2395 0xd22f8)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

What i need to do to run my application in older iOS Version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be  its problem at your new created nib in new xcode with ios6 just unchecked AutoLayout like this :-

Tap on nib->show the FileInspector->

[image]

then Unchecked Use Autolayout as like bellow image;-

[image]

i hope you solve your prob